# Using a stepper once in a while

Tags: cardio, interval-training

When visiting my parents I have access to their stepper.I only visit them every now and then - lets assume once a month I can use the stepper.

I don't have a specific goal, I normally ride bike and run as main cardio-activities, but on the stepper I don't necessarily try to support those activities, it is more like a welcome variety.

I tried to do something interval-ish today, I wonder if there are any good guidelines or recommendations how to make use of that machine. The time I spent and want to spend is 30 minutes; I normally do one session between weightlifting and sauna.

As an example, the intensities of the exercise I did today:

[image: stepper intensities]

The intensities translate to a number of 20cm steps per minute:

```
lvl steps
14  138
10  104
 6   69
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have  pretty solid interval routine.  Like any cardio (or strength) training, how you train depends on your goals.  The way you are doing it probably gives you the most bang-for-your-buck as far as calorie burning goes.  Personally, I would probably just work to stay in the high-intensity range a bit longer every time.  A heart-rate monitor will really be the key to determining what intensity to train at though (again, depending on your goals).

Answer (score 1):

I run a lot and lift moderately.  I would love to add more stair stepping in.  It is a good alternative to running and it is easy on the ankles and feet.  I think the most important key is to keep those reps moving.  Anytime you hit a new machine treat the first few sessions as a baseline and try to improve.

To get a good workout keep the pace going - what this means is do not increase the intensity.  Your legs need to move, not get tired.  Once you get to the point where you can move fast enough where you hit a ceiling or that the machine becomes unstable, then up the intensity.  Work hard the first few times then improve.  The graph looked OK.  In the middle of the workout I think the valleys were a little low but looks OK.